# No space between the text and the border line in a table and misalignment in the border

Tags: latex

I have created the following table in LaTeX:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c||cccc||cccc||} 
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Group1} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Group2} \\ \cline{2-9}
    & \rotatebox{90}{Column First} & \rotatebox{90}{Column Second} & \rotatebox{90}{Column Third} & \rotatebox{90}{Column Fourth} & \rotatebox{90}{Column Fifth} & \rotatebox{90}{Column Sixth} & \rotatebox{90}{Column Seventh} & \rotatebox{90}{Column Eighth} \\ \hline \hline
    Row 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\% & 6\% & 7\% & 8\% \\
    Row 2 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13\% & 14\% & 15\% & 16\% \\ 
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

However, as the blue arrow shows, there is no space between the text and the borderline and the top border is nearly stuck to the word "Seventh". Is there any way that I can create some space there?

There is also another issue regarding the table border. I don't understand why the left and right borders (indicated by red arrows) are not in the same height and the right one is shorter. Is there a way to fix this and make their height equal?

Comment: please make a [mre] including all the necessary package etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- there is no double line besides "Group 2" because you are using `c` as argument for the multicolumn, which says "draw the cell without lines". If you want the lines to be drawn, use `c||`
- to get more space above "Column Seventh", you can manually add `\space` or similar

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c||cccc||cccc||} 
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Group1} & \multicolumn{4}{c||}{Group2} \\ \cline{2-9}
    & \rotatebox{90}{Column First} & \rotatebox{90}{Column Second} & \rotatebox{90}{Column Third} & \rotatebox{90}{Column Fourth} & \rotatebox{90}{Column Fifth} & \rotatebox{90}{Column Sixth} & \rotatebox{90}{Column Seventh\space} & \rotatebox{90}{Column Eighth} \\ \hline \hline
    Row 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\% & 6\% & 7\% & 8\% \\
    Row 2 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13\% & 14\% & 15\% & 16\% \\ 
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```